# Is there a difference in using .html.twig vs .twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, slim

What is the difference between using .html.twig and .twig? Is there some kind of standard, is it framework specific, or is it just user preference?

Answer (score 6):

Under Symfony you have the possibility to deliver different formats automatically. So you can create files like `test.json.twig`, `test.xml.twig` for example. If you define all that extensions in your controller you can deliver all that formats under one action.

For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}.{_format}", defaults={"_format"="html"}, name="_demo_hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name) {
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

Something like this. So you can use the format in your route to define the response format.

Comment: So if you're pulling in twig into a slim app or just using the twig api theres no advantage by using .html.twig?

Comment: It's the common way to use the twig templates and the formats. So you should use it. For programmers it's very good to see which format the file has. But it's your choice how you would use it. So i would prefer to use the format in the file name.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-suffix)

"this is simply an organizational tactic used in case the same resource needs to be rendered as HTML (index.html.twig), XML (index.xml.twig), or any other format."

So sounds like this is user preference, but a good standard to follow either way.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is the behavior of auto escaping.

Imagine you have a `var` variable containing: `<div>I'm happy</div>`.

On `index.twig`, `{{ var }}` will render `<div>I'm happy</div>`.

On `index.html.twig`, `{{ var }}` will render `&lt;div&gt;I&#039;m happy&lt;div&gt;`

On `index.js.twig`, `{{ var }}` will render `\x3Cdiv\x3EI\x27m\x20happy\x3Cdiv\x3E`

And so on.

Always use the right extension to avoid any XSS vulnerability, and always use `|raw` wisely because it overlaps this extension's implicit protection.